# Add Pan button to C# WinForm eDrawings viewer

Tags: c#, winforms, interface, autodesk-viewer, pan

I have a WinForm application that opens AutoCAD drawings in the eDrawings Control. There is an interface for this, with [public methods and properties](http://help.solidworks.com/2014/English/api/emodelapi/eDrawings.Interop.EModelViewControl~eDrawings.Interop.EModelViewControl.IEModelViewControl_members.html) and [enums](http://help.solidworks.com/2017/English/api/emodelapi/eDrawings.Interop.EModelViewControl~eDrawings.Interop.EModelViewControl.EMVOperators.html).

Here is the dilemma: There is a built in `Pan` option in the eDrawings ActiveX Control (which I'm using in my WinForm), *but*, you have to press down the scroll button on your mouse to pan, *or* you have to right click on the drawing, select `View` and then `Pan`. Some users don't have a scroll wheel on their mouse, so they have to `right click -> View -> Pan` for every single drawing, each time they open it. And they don't like it at all (the default goes back to `Select` when the new drawings are opened). So, my task is to somehow create a button or checkbox or something that can select the `Pan` option when the button/checkbox is clicked/checked, so the user can have Pan set as the default when switching between drawings without having to manually select the `Pan` option every single time.

I currently have just used the defaults that came with the eDrawings control, and haven't had to use the interface, but now when I have this task to create an option for the default to be set to Pan, I'm not sure how else to do it, other than with the interface - so my question here, is: Does anyone know how I can implement this option from the interface in my WinForm project?

Comment: Have you tried setting `control.ViewOperator = EMVOperators.eMVOperatorPan`?

Comment: Oh wow, how simple :) That works! Of all the different things I tried, I never got to that point, but I really appreciate your quick response! :)

Comment: I would like to double check if you're using [Autodesk Forge Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/) under Winform

Comment: No, I used the eDrawings Viewer.